# Python - slice array at different position on every row

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a 2D python array that I want to slice in an odd way - I want a constant width slice starting on a different position on every row. I would like to do this in a vectorised way if possible.

e.g. I have the array `A=np.array([range(5), range(5)])` which looks like

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

I would like to slice this as follows: 2 elements from each row, starting at positions 0 and 3. The starting posiitons are stored in `b=np.array([0,3])`. Desired output is thus: `np.array([[0,1],[3,4]])` i.e.

```
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

The obvious thing I tried to get this result was `A[:,b:b+2]` but that doesn't work, and I can't find anything that will.

Speed is important as this will operate on a largish array in a loop, and I don't want to bottleneck other parts of my code.

Comment: There's something in `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`... not to mention a dupe somewhere...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it easier for us to answer your question without having to do a lot of extra work ourselves :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one approach with `broadcasting` to get all indices and then using `advanced-indexing` to extract those -

```
def take_per_row(A, indx, num_elem=2):
    all_indx = indx[:,None] + np.arange(num_elem)
    return A[np.arange(all_indx.shape[0])[:,None], all_indx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [340]: A
Out[340]: 
array([[0, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 7],
       [1, 7, 4, 0, 5, 1, 5, 4],
       [0, 8, 8, 6, 8, 6, 3, 1],
       [2, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3]])

In [341]: indx = np.array([0,3,1,5,2])

In [342]: take_per_row(A, indx)
Out[342]: 
array([[0, 5],
       [1, 3],
       [7, 4],
       [6, 3],
       [2, 5]])
```

**Approach #2 :** Using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def take_per_row_strided(A, indx, num_elem=2):
    m,n = A.shape
    A.shape = (-1)
    s0 = A.strides[0]
    l_indx = indx + n*np.arange(len(indx))
    out = as_strided(A, (len(A)-num_elem+1, num_elem), (s0,s0))[l_indx]
    A.shape = m,n
    return out
```

**Runtime test for taking `200` per row from a `2000x4000` matrix**

```
In [447]: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(2000,4000))

In [448]: indx = np.random.randint(0,4000-200,(2000))

In [449]: out1 = take_per_row(A, indx, 200)

In [450]: out2 = take_per_row_strided(A, indx, 200)

In [451]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[451]: True

In [452]: %timeit take_per_row(A, indx, 200)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.14 ms per loop

In [453]: %timeit take_per_row_strided(A, indx, 200)
1000 loops, best of 3: 435 µs per loop
```

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming this should be the fastest method?

Comment: That's usually a good assumption.  It is @Divakar after all.  That said, this is just my answer wrapped in a function and made a bit more general

Comment: I got 20 nanoseconds for taking 200 per row from a 2000x4000 matrix, so I'm gonna stick with this. Thanks

Comment: @Shakespeare Check out Approach#2 as well.

Comment: @Divakar 1.5ms for approach 2!

Comment: Yeah, you're making an awful lot of windows in Approach #2 just to throw 99.9% of them out via indexing.  They don't take any memory but they do take time to make.

Comment: @DanielF I thought we were extracting from the view. Might be forcing a copy there.

Comment: Fancy indexing *does* do a silent copy.  But I'm more talking about the `as_strided` call itself, as with such a small window you're still doing a not-insignificant amount of work creating the views, 99% of which you never use.

Comment: @DanielF I meant `viewW(A, (1,num_elem))` is simply creating a view (no extra memory allocated there). But the appended operations might be forcing a copy before extracting the required elements.

Comment: @Shakespeare Think I improve approach #2. Check that out again? It appears to be much faster than #1.

Comment: @DanielF Seems like I am avoiding the copy in the updated version.

Comment: Not so sure, if I do `take_per_row_strided(A, indx).flags`, I get `OWNDATA : True`.  I think you just found a more efficient way to copy.

Comment: @DanielF The extracted elements would of course be a copy. I meant its not making a copy before that extraction. In my earlier approach, it was probably forcing a copy before extraction, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I must have timed it wrong before as I get 5ms for approach 1 now and 1.3 for approach 2. Seems to be slightly faster than the scipy version. Btw, this is a great answer :)

Comment: @Shakespeare `1.3` sec or m-sec for app#2?

Comment: milliseconds, i.e. it's faster

Comment: @Shakespeare Awesome! That is coherent with my timing results.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.take()`:

```
In [21]: slices = np.dstack([b, b+1])

In [22]: np.take(arr, slices)
Out[22]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [3, 4]]])
```

Comment: Would this be slow for larger slices and arrays? I'm interested in slicing about 200 elements per row from a matrix of size approximately 2000x4000

Comment: @Shakespeare Size `2000x4000` is not that large. But still there might be some ways to enhance the performance, like using broadcasting and direct slicing instead of using `take`.

Comment: Ok I will look into it, it's important for it to run quickly since it feeds data to another part of my program in a loop

Comment: I think you need an `axis = 1` keyword if the rows of `A` are not equal

Comment: And you'll end up with an extra dimension you'll have to deal with in that case.

Comment: @DanielF If the rows of `A` are not equal it will be a array of object type and you need to deal with it in another way.

Comment: I mean the rows are not equal *valued* (in the question every row is `range(5)`).

Comment: Granted,in the question a too specific example is considered in comparison with the general question being asked. Nevertheless, this is NOT! an answer to the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a fancy indexing method to find the correct elements:

```
A = np.arange(10).reshape(2,-1)

x = np.stack([np.arange(A.shape[0])]* 2).T
y = np.stack([b, b+1]).T
A[x, y]

array([[0, 1],
       [8, 9]])
```

Compare to @Kasramvd's `np.take` answer:

```
slices = np.dstack([b, b+1])
np.take(A, slices)

array([[[0, 1],
        [3, 4]]])
```

[`np.slice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) by default takes from the *flattened* array, not row-wise.  with an `axis = 1` parameter you get all the slices of all the rows:

```
np.take(A, slices, axis = 1)

array([[[[0, 1],
         [3, 4]]],


       [[[5, 6],
         [8, 9]]]])
```

Which would need more processing.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, went with Divakar's as it's a bit more polished